# Entity Framework Database Generation Power Pack?

Tags: entity-framework

I  use Model-first with EF, and I want to have an automated gap DDL script when I change my model. With "Entity Framework Database Generation Power Pack" We had it in past, but I read that was not supported in VS2012.

Any changes about that?

For Who dont't understand this need, I would like to remmember that in production enviroments, development team dosen't have access to DB. We must create and send to production Support team, DDL deployment scripts that preserve data and all DB without any recreation.

Comment: Your question seems quite broad (actually too broad) and can attract many opinion-based answers, which aren't too welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Database.SetInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx), which mainly determines what happens if there is no database present when the application is started for the first time, and [migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/data/jj591621.aspx) which can be used to update the datebase when a new application version (which requires an updated database) has been deployed. If the built-in support for migrations data aren't enough, you also have the ability to add raw SQL data to handle migrating to a new version.